# Can a false ceiling improve insulation?

Tags: insulation, roof

My new house has a very small kitchen which is actually an extension of the house with its own roof.

I suspect its roof insulation is old and not effective, because this kitchen is quite cold (12 degres celsius sometimes).

Landlord says he doesn't want to inspect insulation because it's contained in a waterproof membrane and we could create a leak just by opening it to look into it.

I was thinking about installing a false ceiling inside my kitchen to improve insulation and prevent heat from escaping so much. The room is like 4 square meters. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Questions about cost are generally considered off topic here, since prices vary by region and over time.

Comment: I think you should investigate further before making a decision.  Get a cheap IR thermometer and see what temperature your ceiling is vs. a wall for instance.  Make sure your windows are sealed well also. Yes, a false ceiling will add some insulating value but probably not much unless you lay some batting on top of it.

Comment: You mention a landlord. You need to look into your lease agreement and discuss any modifications with your landlord.

Comment: ethereal: are you sure a neat difference of temperature between walls and ceiling would demonstrate that there is an insulation problem? And conversely, if there is no clear difference does it mean there is no insulation problem?